# How could I use a use a regex-like procedure on a code string with a macro in Rust?

Tags: rust

I've written multiple functions in my code that have snippets that are duplicated three times, for red blue and green. It's getting pretty old and cluttering up my code, and I would prefer to compress them each into one snippet encapsulated in a macro. However, I can't find any information in the book about a macro that would operate like this, even though generating code is their sole purpose. Ideally, it would look something like this:

```
rgb_triple!("
for i in 0..(data.dimensions.width * data.dimensions.height) {
    $color_map[i] = 255;
}
")
```

expanding to this:

```
for i in 0..(data.dimensions.width * data.dimensions.height) {
    red_map[i] = 255;
}
for i in 0..(data.dimensions.width * data.dimensions.height) {
    green_map[i] = 255;
}
for i in 0..(data.dimensions.width * data.dimensions.height) {
    blue_map[i] = 255;
}
```

What would be the best way for me to do this (even if this isn't)?

Answer (score 2):

I would write a function that takes the color_map as mutable reference. Something like:

```rust
fn do_it(color_map: &mut Vec<u32>, data: &Data) {
    for i in 0..(data.dimensions.width * data.dimensions.height) {
        color_map[i] = 255;
    }
}
```

Comment: color map isn’t a variable in this situation, I think you misread the question; I was showing that the $color would be replaced by red, green, and blue by the macro

Comment: @PunkyMunky64, you just have to call `do_it` 3 times (once for each of red_map, green_map, and blue_map). Of course you can write a function to do that as well, and then just call that. Macros are for when you want to introduce new syntax, which you don't.

Comment: never mind I misread your response, I see now. thanks for the answer but that kinda defeats the point for me. I feel like it would be annoying for a function to just contain three calls of another function where the reader would have to divert their attention to. it would compress the code but not give it the abstraction that would help.